# Не хочет запускаться установщик linux с флешки

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, bios, uefi

[image: вот сама ошибка]У меня UEFI bios там отключён security boot.  Флешка: kingston на 60гигов

Недавно я принял решение перейти временно (или навсегда) на linux. Выбрал дистрибутив(Ubuntu) и принялся подготавливать флешку. Скачал образ с оф. сайта последней версии и при помощи программы rufus я сделал установочную флешку. Захожу в биос и выбираю флешку. И вместо запуска выходит эта ошибка(на фото) и через 3-4 секунды комп окончательно отключается. Пробовал копировать образ через другие программы но это не помогает и так с некоторыми дистрибутивами(Mint, Arch). До этого момента у меня спокойно загружались флешки с Live Cd до этого момента...
Я отмечу что я не лазил в настройках биос и что раньше такой ошибки у меня не выскакивало. В интернете я информацию не нашёл. В linux я ещё новичок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно очистить MOK (ключи владельца машины). Их скопилось слишком много.

mokutil для линукс.

```
sudo mokutil --reset
```

Или ищи параметр сброса в БИОС, или ресетни БИОС через батарейку.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Сброс биос помог с этой ошибкой